# java command line requires JDK on Mac?

Tags: java, macos

I've installed JRE 1.8 on MacOS X 10.10 from the official Oracle site. The file I've installed was `jre-8u66-macosx-x64.dmg`. To my surprise, the `java` command says I need JDK for it to work.

Is there a way to execute a jar from the command line on Mac without JDK? If not, what options for running Java code are there (other than browser applets)?

EDIT: when invoking `java -v` from the command line, I get the following output:

> No Java runtime present, requesting install.

and an alert window, which says:

> To use the "java" command-line tool you need to install a JDK.

One more data point: the folder /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines is empty. Instead, there's stuff under `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`. It even has a command-line `java` under /bin/. Running it with `-version` gives:

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

I wonder if I can somehow leverage that one for CLI..

Comment: what is the exact message you get when you try to run `java`?

Comment: Also depends on what you're trying to run.  Tomcat requires JDK, for instance.

Comment: Can you update your question to include how you installed the JRE?  Was it from the official Oracle JRE downloads?

Comment: Official. Updated my question.

Comment: did you try re-installing it? To me it looks like the installation did not properly complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case a re-install does not fix the problem, you could set $JAVA_HOME to the location java is installed:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

After that, `java -v` should work, but you'll have to do it for every new terminal window, or add it to `.bash_profile` or other file depending on the shell you use.

Comment: Found that one out myself, but let this sit here for posterity's sake :)

Comment: Still needed in 2020 on macOS Catalina

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Full Java functionality on the command line requires the SDK.

The SDK provides a Java install that includes OS-specific libs that are not included for the applet runner.
I suppose some subset of Java apps and applets might run ok from the command line, but the applet plugin provides different services.

This has annoyed me for years, since now and again I need a Java environment, but most of the time would prefer to have no trace of it on my system. Even when I do have the browser plugin installed, it's usually disabled.

Answer (score 1):

When you get this message and you already have the JDK installed or no JDK installed, it is often the case that the application you are using requires a previous version of the SDK.

[image]

From this [page](https://java.com/en/download/faq/yosemite_java.xml) on Java.com:

> This is most commonly because an application requires the legacy Java 6 provided by Apple. For the solution to this issue, see http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572.

It redirects to a [page](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) on Apple's site to download and install the previous version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if it tells you that a newer version of Java has installed on my machine, and I couldn't get the 2017 version installed to fix problems, any ideas how then？