# Using Oracle Java VM in-process on Mac

Tags: java, macos, jvm

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074039/java-command-line-requires-jdk-on-mac).

MacOS X has the `java` command under `/usr/bin`. If one installs the JRE from Oracle, it doesn't work - claims there's no Java runtime, and offers to download and install Apple's runtime. But if you first run

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

then `java` works as expected. That's where Oracle JRE installs itself.

---

Now I'd like to use the Oracle Java VM in-process, and I can't - the "You need Java runtime" error message keeps popping up, even with JAVA_HOME being set.

Linking against the `JavaVM` framework causes the message on app startup, even before main().

Trying to dynamically load `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib` and invoke `JNI_CreateJavaVM` causes the same message during the method call.

EDIT: the `java` command does it somehow, after all. I've poked around with a debugger, it does invoke JNI_CreateJavaVM at some point. I've even mimicked the arguments (there's one extra one, `-Dsun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD`), it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8064542).

Instead of loading libjvm.dylib, one needs to load `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib`. It exports `JNI_CreateJavaVM`, too. Call that one, and it'll work as expected.

Works even with `JAVA_HOME` not being set.

Future warning: Oracle says that since Java 1.9, the browser plugin technology will no longer be supported. With that in mind, Oracle JRE's home in version 1.9 might not be under `Internet Plug-Ins` anymore.